# How to print a new line after each printing call

Tags: java

I want to get as many stars i give in the function with a line break. But I am not able to get them with line break.

```
public class prac11 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //printStars(1);
        printStars(2);
        printStars(3);
    }

    public static void printStars(int x) {
        int i=1;
        while(i<=x) {
            System.out.print("*");
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

[image: My output]

[image: Desired Output]

Answer (score 5):

You have to add a [println](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println--) statement to put the linebreak after your loop:

```
public class prac11 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printStars(5);
        printStars(3);
        printStars(9);
    }

    public static void printStars(int x) {
        int i=1;
        while(i<=x) {
            System.out.print("*");
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println(); // this will produce a linebreak
    }
}
```

Output:

```
*****
***
*********
```

Comment: @Harsha please read: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Add `System.out.println()` after the while loop, to get the linebreak.